# tapされたあとの処理を流れるようにUILabel.textまでメソッドチェーンで書きたい

Tags: swift3, reactive-programming, rx-swift

```
import UIKit
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonB: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelB: UILabel!

    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    var countVariable = Variable(0)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        countVariable.asObservable().map{ String($0) }.bind(to: labelB.rx.text).disposed(by: disposeBag)
        buttonB.rx.tap.subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] in
            guard let weakSelf = self else { return }

            weakSelf.countVariable.value = weakSelf.countVariable.value + 1
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
}
```

上記の処理のながれを

`tap -> countVariableを1プラスする処理 -> String変換 -> ラベルのテキスト`

というように流れるようにメソッドチェーンでつなげて書く方法はありませんでしょうか？

ソースからおわかりと思いますが、
今段階で掲載したソースでメソッドチェーンとして流れるようにつながっているのは、
`String変換 -> ラベルのテキスト`の部分のみです。
流れるようにプログラムが書けるともっとソースが読みやすくなると思っております。

仮に
`tap -> countVariableを1プラスする処理 -> String変換 -> ラベルのテキスト`
の流れがRx的に不自然なのであれば、流れる順番を修正していただいてかまいません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RxSwiftの `Variable` は `BehaviorSubject` （RxSwift4では `BehaviorRelay` ）のラッパーであり、ご質問のソースに書いていただいたような処理をしたい場合には2方向のバインディングを行うのが基本となります。なので、一つのメソッドチェーンでまとめて書くということはできません。

Variableを挟まずに、直接ストリームをつなげるようにすれば一つのメソッドチェーンで書くことができます。

```swift
self.buttonB.rx.tap
    .scan(0) { count, _ in count + 1 } // 初期値0に対し、タップのたびに1を足していく
    .map { String($0) }
    .bind(to: self.labelB.rx.text)
    .disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
```

Comment: なるほど！これは参考になります！改良を加えて
`scan(countVariable) { cv, _ in cv.value = cv.value + 1; return cv }.map { String($0.value) }`
に変えるとVariableを使ってもうまくいきました。改良版の書き方はいかがでしょうか？

Comment: その書き方ですとあまりVariableを使用する意味が無いように思います。また、Rxのオペレーターの処理中で外部の変数を書き換えるのは副作用を及ぼすコードでバグを発生させやすいので好ましくありません。

Comment: なるほど。ありがとうございます。